# There are 8 special methods in tuple which are not inherited from `object` and `type

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I check the special methods of type  tuple

```
In [114]: [m for m in dir(tuple) if m.startswith("__")]
Out[114]: 
['__add__',
 '__class__',
 '__contains__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dir__',
```

I found that some dudermethods are not inherited either from `object` or `type`

```
In [115]: meta_methods = set(dir(object)) | set(dir(type))
In [116]: len(meta_methods)
Out[116]: 43

In [117]: [m for m in dir(tuple) if m not in meta_methods]
Out[117]: 
['__add__',
 '__contains__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__getnewargs__',
 '__iter__',
 '__len__',
 '__mul__',
 '__rmul__',
 'count',
 'index']
```

There are 8 special methods which are not inherited from `object` and `type`.

Where does the methods come from?

Comment: `tuple` is a subclass of `object` and implements methods.  `tuple` is not the same class as `object`.

Comment: You are surprised that `tuple` has a `__getitem__` but object does not?  Is that the question?

Comment: For that matter, why are you checking the methods of the metaclass?

Comment: Yes, that is my question @StephenRauch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I showed you this class:

```
class Foo:
    def this_is_a_method(self):
        print('tacos')
```

Or maybe this class:

```
class Underscores:
    def __this_is_a_method_with_underscores__(self):
        print("It's just a method.")
    def __len__(self):
        return 12
```

Would you be surprised that it has a method that `object` and `type` don't have?

Same thing with `tuple`. `tuple` has its own methods. That's a thing classes can do - they can have their own methods. Not all methods have to come from `object` or `type`. This is a perfectly ordinary part of the class system.